# script works on jsfiddle, not on local machine

Tags: jquery, xampp, jsfiddle

I am really new to jquery and I am having some trouble getting this to work on my local machine.

http://jsfiddle.net/ze8kn/

**HTML**:

```
<div id="callus">
    <div class="def">location 0</div>
    <div class='num1'>location 1</div>
    <div class='num2'>location 2</div>
    <div class='num3'>location 3</div>
    <div class='num4'>location 4</div>
    <div class="numnames numname1">1234</div>
    <div class="numnames numname2">5678</div>
    <div class="numnames numname3">1234</div>
    <div class="numnames numname4">5678</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.numnames').hover(function() {
            $(".def").toggle();
        });
        $('.num1').hide();
        $('.numname1').hover(function() {
            $('.num1').toggle();
            return false;
        });
        $('.num2').hide();
        $('.numname2').hover(function() {
            $('.num2').toggle();
            return false;
        });
        $('.num3').hide();
        $('.numname3').hover(function() {
            $('.num3').toggle();
            return false;
        });
        $('.num4').hide();
        $('.numname4').hover(function() {
            $('.num4').toggle();
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

It's chunky, I know, but at least it does what I want it to.
It works perfectly on jsfiddle, but it doesn't do anything when I am testing it on my local server.

Comment: have you included properly the jquery source? try including this `<script type="text/javascript" src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` and see if it works.

Comment: "but it doesn't do anything". It does *something*. What error messages do you see in your dev console?

Comment: That fiddle is in dire need for a visit to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Hamish None of the error messages are related to jQuery

Comment: @dqlopez Added jQuery source, still no game

Comment: Might as well show your html source files.

Comment: @Ben.chmark Annnnd..... what are they?

Comment: @Ben.chmark - I don't see any problem, post the whole HTML you have. Try clearing all your scripts then replace with this `​$(function(){alert("HEY");});​​​​​`, there should appear a popup box.

Comment: Please read the http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/faq.html#code-is-working-on-jsfiddle-not-on-site-local-machine

Comment: The good news is I've gotten it to work. The bad news is that it only works on some of the pages. On one of the pages where there is another jQuery instance running, it is not playing nice.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$(function() {` and the last row.